# Is it possible to automatically verify Python type stub package?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I've created the package [openpyxl-stubs](https://github.com/MartinThoma/openpyxl-stubs) to provide type stubs for openpyxl. I'm not super familiar with openpyxl and I don't have a lot of time for this small project.

It would be really nice if I could somehow find obvious issues with my stubs, e.g.

- Missing modules: Modules which are in openpyxl, but not in the stubs
- Deprecated modules: Modules which are no longer in openpyxl, but still in the stubs
- Missing or deprecated classes/methods/functions
- Issues in the annotations, e.g. missing annotations for parameters/return values

How can I check for those issues?